# Where did the text of my .html file go in TextEdit on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, text-editing

I recently created a .html file in TextEdit on my Mac (Mac OS X 10.5.8). I then opened that .html file in my browser and it showed the page I created just fine. I closed the .html file and TextEdit and refreshed the page. It still worked fine. Then I opened up the .html file in TextEdit again and all the text was gone (the page in the browser still works fine though). Where did all the text go?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Agree with Mike.

Answer (score 3):

Try selecting "Ignore rich text commands in HTML files" in the Open/Save section of TextEdit's preferences window.

Edit: after making sure this option is set, you'll likely need to re-open the file.

Answer (score 2):

TextEdit was trying to render the page and present it rather than letting you edit the source.  You should consider using a real editor.

Comment: textEdit is a Rich Text editor and will not always display the plain text output. An editor like TextWrangler might be better suited.

Comment: @jweede: TextEdit can be used as a plain text editor. However as you mentioned TextWrangler is *much* better suited.

Answer (score 1):

TextEdit is converting the HTML to rich text and displaying it as it is marked up by the tags. TextEdit is considered a rich text editor and not suitable for HTML or coding use.

You should use a raw text editor like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) if you plan on doing coding or html work.